# Python: Converting a tuple to a string

Tags: python, string, tuples

Given this  :

```
import os
import subprocess

def check_server():

    cl = subprocess.Popen(["nmap","10.7.1.71"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = cl.communicate()
    print result

check_server()
```

check_server() returns this tuple:

```
('\nStarting Nmap 4.53 ( http://insecure.org ) at 2010-04-07 07:26 EDT\nInteresting ports on 10.7.1.71:\nNot shown: 1711 closed ports\nPORT   STATE SERVICE\n21/tcp open  ftp\n22/tcp open  ssh\n80/tcp open  http\n\nNmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.293 seconds\n', None)
```

Changing the second line in the method to

```
result, err = cl.communicate()
```

results in check_server() returning :

```
Starting Nmap 4.53 ( http://insecure.org ) at 2010-04-07 07:27 EDT
Interesting ports on 10.7.1.71:
Not shown: 1711 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.319 seconds
```

Looks to be the case that the tuple is converted to a string, and the \n's are being stripped.... but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cl.communicate()` is still returning a tuple. The assignment `result, err = ...` has the effect of unpacking the tuple into the variables `result` (a string) and `err` (an integer).

When you print the tuple, it uses the `repr(...)` of each element, but when you print the string, it just prints the string, hence the absence of delimiters and `\n`s.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases `cl.communicate()` returns a two-element tuple (stdout and stderr of the command if both stdout and stderr are redirected to a PIPE). In first case you assign this tuple to the `result` variable. When you print it you get a text representation of the tuple. Special characters, like end-of-line are escaped (to '\n') in such representation.

In the second case you unpack the tuple. This means: you assign the first element of the tuple to `result` and the second to `err`. As the `result` is already a string it is printed with no escaping – end-of-line characters are displayed as line breaks and not '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is clever.  If you pass it a string, it just prints it.  If you pass it something else (a tuple in this example) then it prints it's representation (as returned by `repr()`).

The representation of a string has `\n` where the string contains newlines.  The representation also has quotes around it.

Try changing your `print` statement to `print repr(result)` and you'll see.

Comment: `print` doesn't use `__repr__()` if `__str__()` is available, but standard sequence types do use `__repr__()` for printing their elements.